# Regarding with the apache configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, godaddy

I registered a domain in GoDaddy.I setup a few items in my A records:

```
subdomain.mydomain.com 1.2.3.4
mydomain.com           1.2.3.4
www.mydomain.com       1.2.3.4
```

In my ubuntu server apache virtual host setting:

subdomain.mydomain.com -> /var/www/subdomain
   mydomain.com           -> /var/www/public_html

It works. But there is an issue. When I key in an ip address in my browser, the /var/www/ directory will be listed.My question is how can I configure to redirect the ip address to /var/www/public_html and disable /var/www directory listing?

Comment: You should spend some time reading the documentation on name based virtual hosting.

Comment: Any suggestion?